# Visual studio preview (for MAC) throws System.dllNotFoundException

Tags: c#, .net

I have written a simple code for reading and excel file and AutoFilter the data and saved the filtered data in another file. But it give System.dllNotFoundException error. 
Though I tried placing System.dll and Ole32.dll in the same folder as of solution but still no luck!!

Comment: You need to include way more information.  Like your code, what line the exception happens on, ...

Comment: Would be great if there was some code to back this question along with error position

Comment: You need MS Excel and the Office PIA installed to use Interop.Excel